# Evaluate the integral. $\int _\sqrt{2} ^2 x\ln(x^4-1) \, \mathrm dx.$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate the integral $$\int    _\sqrt{2}    ^2     
> x\ln(x^4-1)
> \,
> \mathrm dx.$$

As a hint it says that:

> You can use the fact that $$\int \ln x\,\mathrm dx=x\ln x-x+\mathrm C.$$

at least,if you can say what method I should use(partial ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Setting $u=x^2,$

$$\int_\sqrt2^2x\ln(x^4-1)dx=\frac12\int_2^4\ln(u^2-1)du$$

$$\int \ln(u^2-1)du=\ln(u^2-1)\int du-\int\left(\int du\cdot\frac{d\ln(u^2-1)}{du}\right)du$$

$$=u\ln(u^2-1)-\int\frac{2u^2}{u^2-1}du$$

Now,   $$\frac{2u^2}{u^2-1}=2+\frac 2{u^2-1}=2+\frac{u+1-(u-1)}{u^2-1}=2+\frac1{u-1}-\frac1{u+1}$$

Comment: Or, even better, use the fact that $\ln(u^2-1)=\ln[(u-1)(u+1)]=\ln(u-1)+\ln(u+1)$.

Comment: @Lucian, thanks for the input.

Comment: @Lucian thank you the hint makes sense now